# Why this htaccess file is not working in wamp server

Tags: php, .htaccess, wamp, wampserver

I have this htaccess file it redirects to index.php when url is of type   www.mywebsite.com/news
but when url is of type www.mywebsite.com/news/2 it shows index.html but no css is applied
I am on wamp server

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `/news/2` creates a virtual directory.
Since you're using **relative** paths for your html links, it does not work.

Let's imagine you have a css link like this one
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">`
Since your URI is `/news/2` it will search in `/news/style.css` and that's not what you want.

Instead, use **absolute** paths.
For example: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css">` (with a leading slash, and maybe another base if it's not in root folder).

Also, it wouldn't hurt to put a `RewriteBase /` in your htaccess (or a leading slash before `index.php`)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

---

EDIT: for your project `/project_news/` on localhost

- You have to change all your html links this way (add `/project_news` prefix)
  `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/project_news/css/style.css">`
- Or, if you don't want to change all links, you can also add `<base href="/project_news/">` right after `<head>` html tag (in all your html pages concerned)

Then, replace your current htaccess code by this one

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /project_news/

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Hi 
Bro I am working on wamp local server
ans when i add RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L] it redirects me to localserver main page and my css 
is like <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/sidepanel.css" type="text/css">

Comment: You should write it in your question, otherwise it's not exactly the same. Could you tell me in which folder is your project ? (Which localhost-url do you use to reach it ?) What about css folder, is it in project folder too ?

Comment: my project is in project_news
yeah css is in same folder
localhost/project_news

Comment: Ok you can see my edited answer about that, should work as expected right now